# Best way to create singleton array

Tags: java, arrays

What is the "easiest" way for you to create a singleton (with exactly one element) Objects array in Java ?

Comment: You should know, that when using an array, the content is mutable. Consider using a singleton set usin `Collections.singletonSet(element)`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
Object [] singleton = { new SomeObject() };
```

Comment: Too bad this cannot be used without type annotation, e.g. you cannot pass the right part as function argument.

Answer (score 26):

The standard way is this:

```
String[] arr = new String[]{"I am the one and only"};
```

I'm afraid it doesn't get much simpler than this.

Edit: it does:

```
String[] arr = {"I am the one and only"};
```

Thanks aioobe, I keep forgetting this.

---

Of course if you often create array you can create a helper method that makes things a bit simpler:

```
public static <T> T[] asArray(T... items){
    return items;
}

String[] arr = asArray("I am the one and only");
```

(But you can't enforce at compile time that it will be an array with only one element)

---

Next I was going to write a singleton array method, but [Stephen beat me to that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582502/best-way-to-create-singleton-array/3582532#3582532).

Comment: "I'm afraid it doesn't get much simpler than this.". In that particular line, you may remove `new String[]` :-)

Comment: To be fair, the 'normal' notation really isn't that difficult.

Answer (score 14):

If your project is already using Apache Commons lib, you can stick to `ArrayUtils.toArray()` method.

```
String[] arr = ArrayUtils.toArray("The string");
// or if using static import
String[] arr = toArray("The string");
```

Even if using static import it is still more verbose than the accepted answer:

```
String[] arr = {"The string"};
```

But it comes very handy when compact array initializer syntax is not allowed.

Some examples:

```
someMethod(toArray("The string"), /* other params */);

return toArray("The string");

@DataProvider
public Object[][] someDataProvider() {
    return rangeClosed(-12, +12)
        .map(HOURS::toMillis).boxed()
        .map(ArrayUtils::toArray)
        .toArray(Object[][]::new);
}
```

You can imagine any other examples yourself.

Also note, that the `ArrayUtils.toArray()` can wrap an arbitrary number of objects into array, not only a single one.

Answer (score 6):

This should do the job

```
public SomeType[] makeSingletonArray(SomeType elem) {
    return new SomeType[]{elem};
}
```

A generic version of this method would be somewhat awkward to use, since you would need to pass it a `Class` object as an additional parameter.

Inlining the `SomeType[]{elem}` expression is simpler, and that's how I'd normally do this.

Answer (score 6):

enum solution(anti reflect attack):

```
enum MySingleton{
    INSTANCE(new String[]{"a","b"});

    final String[] values;

    private MySingleton(String[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

reference it as:

```
MySingleton.INSTANCE;
```

Comment: The OP is asking not for a Singleton (as in an instance of the GOF pattern) but just for how to make an array with one element (also known as a singleton array in English like the singleton* methods in Collections). So, your {"a","b"} is not a singleton array (it has 2 elements) even though it is an instance of the Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

`String[] a = Collections.`[`singletonList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList(T))`("SingleElement").toArray();`

**Edit:** Whoops! The above example doesn't compile. As stated in the comment, this can be done either as:

`Object[] a = Collections.singletonList("SingleElement").toArray();`
Or
`String[] a = Collections.singletonList("SingleElement").toArray(new String[1]);`

Comment: Does not compile. Has to be either `Object[] a = Collections.singletonList("SingleElement").toArray();` or `String[] a = Collections.singletonList("SingleElement").toArray(new String[1]);`

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java are mutable.

But if you want to create a single object in an array, you can do like this:

```
Object[] objArray = new Object[] { put your object here };
```